# search on a split data structure

Tags: probability, inequality

I have the following problem:

> Part 1:   Lets say I have `n` items in a data structure and I want to
>   search for them. I know that a subset of my data $r \cdot n$, with $r
>  \in (0, 1)$ is more probable to be searched for ($p \in [0.5, 1]$)
>   than the rest of my data $(1-r)n$.   If I now split my data structure
>   into two structures, which behave the same way, where I put my $r
>  \cdot n$ items in one and the rest in the other data structure, when
>   is it usually better to do the split and when is it not?
>
> Let $a(n)$ be the average cost to find my data in a data structure
>   with $n$ elements and $b(n)$ the average cost to not find my data.
>   Consider the following inequality:
>
> $p \cdot a(rn) + (1-p) \cdot(b(rn)+a((1-r)n)) \leq a(n)$
>
> The question is, in which case is this inequality true?

I don't really get it. Isn't it highly dependent on the type of data structure?

> Part 2:  Consider the data structure to be a linear (unsorted) list.
>   Provide $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ and prove for which values of $p$ and $r$
>   such a split of the data structure is lucrative.

My solution to part 2:
If I'm not mistaken $a(n)=\frac{n}{2} = b(n)$ so if I put this into the inequation I get
$n\cdot p \cdot r \leq n \cdot p$ which is always true because $r \in (0, 1)$.
So, I generally understand the equation but I cant figure out when it is generally true without any given specifics.

Comment: Can you edit the question to make it clearer in the formatting which parts are quotation from the test / homework / question, and which parts are _your_ own thoughts / questions?

Comment: Done. You're right. That was a bit convoluted.

Comment: It still wasn't clear so I've edited the question; take a look and see if that's what you intended.

Comment: BTW, $b(n)$ is $n$ for the unsorted list as you always need to look at all elements before concluding it isn't there.